# Automatically set inverse related products

Tags: magento-1, related-products

I need to have that when saving a product it should automatically be set as related to its related products

UPDATED so it also removes the inverse related product when removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a solution add an observer in etc

```
<global>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <name_module>
                    <class>name_module/observer</class>
                    <method>prepareInverseRelation</method>
                </name_module>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <name_module>
                    <class>name_module/observer</class>
                    <method>setInverseRelatedProducts</method>
                </name_module>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

and then in Model/Obserrver.php put this

```
class Name_Module_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function setInverseRelatedProducts($observer){
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();  
        $origid=$product->getId();
        $oldcompare = Mage::registry('oldcompare'.$origid);
        foreach($product->getRelatedProductCollection() as $relpr){
            $oldcompare = array_diff($oldcompare, [$relpr->getId()]);
            $related = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($relpr->getId()); 
            $data = array();
            $save = true;
            foreach($related->getRelatedProductCollection() as $relrel){
                if ($relrel->getId() == $origid){$save = false;}
                $data[$relrel->getId()] = array('position'=>0);
            } 
            $data[$origid] = array('position'=>0);
            if ($save){$related->setRelatedLinkData($data)->save();}
        }
// this part removes the product from any related list that this product is no longer related to 
        if (!empty($oldcompare)){
          foreach($oldcompare as $remove){
            $removep = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($remove); 
            $data2 = array();
            $save2 = false;
            foreach($removep->getRelatedProductCollection() as $rellist){
                if ($rellist->getId() == $origid){
                    $save2 = true;
                } else {$data2[$rellist->getId()] = array('position'=>0);}
            } 
            if ($save2){$removep->setRelatedLinkData($data2)->save();}
          }
        }
        Mage::unregister('oldcompare'.$origid); 
    }

    public function prepareInverseRelation($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();     
        $orriglist = array();
        foreach($product->getRelatedProductCollection() as $origr){
            $orriglist[] = $origr->getId();
        } 
        Mage::register('oldcompare'.$product->getId(), $orriglist);
    }
}
```